# I have old C program, where I can see declaration

Tags: c

I review code of old program and in header after include section I have the following:

```
 extern FILE *yyin,  *yyout;

 TW_LOG_PROC_ERROR;
 TW_TRAN_ACC;
 TW_TVAL;
```

Extern I know, but what is below, I cannot find. I believe there are global variables, but I don't know if it is true and where to find them . Please advise.

Comment: Try using [ack](http://www.beyondgrep.com). It will help find things quickly in your source tree.

Comment: @Nikhil wey! Another ack user :) It's a great tool.

Answer (score 3):

Those could be some sort of macros or the old ["implicit `int` rule"](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=467) where objects without a specified type are considered `int`.

> In K&R C, and pre-standard dialects of C++, **a variable declared
>   without an explicit type name was assumed to be of type int**.

The fact that they are written in caps however would suggest they are macros.

Comment: +1 for someone on the younger side of 40 knowing "implicit int rule".

Comment: @chux, the implicit int rule causes compile-time warnings in today's compilers. Since I compile using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`, I don't like when people haven't removed the implicit declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ctags -R .` on the entire project, you should be able to find the declaration of everything in the project. You can easily find the file and line number of every declaration in the generated `tags` file. There are very many plugins and programs that can handle ctags and prettify them for you.

EDIT:

or just run:

```
grep "TW_LOG_PROC_ERROR" -r .
grep "TW_TRAN_ACC" -r .
grep "TW_TVAL" -r .
```

Comment: Otherwise, `grep` it.